# Chrome.cookies.getAll is undefined from within function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a small extension, primarily using jQuery as an assistant to a message board. On my options/config page I want to be able to check to see if a user is logged in to a certain website.

The page calls a js file called options js and within this file it's very easy to do the following, which works perfectly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  chrome.cookies.getAll({url:"http://mysite.com", name:"mycookiename"}, function(cookies){
    // If the cookie is present.
    if (cookies) {
        // Do stuff
    }
    else {
        // do other stuff
    }
  });
});
```

However, I wanted to be a bit more modular and so put this code into a function that could be called at any time. This unfortunately didn't work and I'm a bit confused as to why.

```
function checkLogin() {
  chrome.cookies.getAll({url:"http://mysite.com", name:"mycookiename"}, function(cookies){
    // If the cookie is present.
    if (cookies) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Call our function
  checkLogin();
});
```

When I test it by logging outputs to the console, it simply tells me "undefined."

Comment: Where is chrome.cookies defined? I'm not used to using the chrome global object, but I checked my console, and it doesn't appear to have a property/field 'cookies'. Are you pushing that onto the object? If so, make sure it's being done before you call checkLogin.

Comment: `chrome.cookies.getAll` is asynchronous, you are using it wrong (after you moved part of the code to a function). Please google "asynchronous function in javascript".